# Separate FOREIGN KEY declaration fails

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-key-relationship

The following CREATE TABLE statement (simplified on purpose) 
works well on current Mysql 5.1 / INNODB:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (  
   id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY  
  ,boss INT REFERENCES Employee  
)
```

Now I try to create the FOREIGN KEY separately (after executing DROP TABLE Employee):

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (  
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY  
  , boss INT  
  ,CONSTRAINT _FK_boss FOREIGN KEY(boss) REFERENCES Employee  
)
```

This time table creation fails with message

> "Cannot add foreign key constraint".

BTW: I already did a DROP/CREATE DATABASE ..., tinkered with the constraint identifier name with no success at all. Adding an explicit `"Engine innodb"` does not help either. My original schema has two distinct 1:n related tables exhibiting identical behavior.

As far as I understand 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html the syntax is alright.

Comment: Please ***READ*** the tags you use before using them. This has nothing to do with *Microsoft SQL Server*.

Answer (score 1):

The first example did *not* work. If you run SHOW CREATE TABLE, you'll see the constraint is not there.

MySQL parses inline foreign key declarations, but InnoDB ignores them. InnoDB supports only table-level constraints. And InnoDB requires the column to be declared explicitly, even though standard SQL says it's optional.

This is an artifact of MySQL's pluggable storage engine architecture. Both the storage-independent layer of MySQL and each individual storage-engine layer has their own SQL parser, and they may not agree on how much of the standard language they support. Another example is CHECK constraints, which are parsed by MySQL, but ignored by all storage engines (so far).

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key constraints *require* the column; it's not optional. This statement will allow the declaration to succeed.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, boss INT
,CONSTRAINT _FK_boss FOREIGN KEY(boss) REFERENCES Employee (id)
);
```